# Extending golang's http package

Tags: http, go, http-status

I would need to extend http package to achieve non standard response containing error description in status ie:
400 Required parameter is missing 
instead of 400 Bad request that is standard status description.

This is my actual implementation:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

type GatewayHandler int

func main() {
    var gh GatewayHandler

    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", gh)
}

func (gh GatewayHandler) ServeHTTP(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    legacyApiUrl := "http://some-url.com" + req.URL.RequestURI()

    client := &http.Client{}
    request, _ := http.NewRequest(req.Method, legacyApiUrl, nil)
    response, _ := client.Do(request)
    res.Header().Set("Status", response.Status)
    for k, v := range response.Header {
        fmt.Println(k, ": ", v)
        i := ""
        for _, j := range v {
            i += j
        }
        res.Header().Set(k, i)
    }

    res.WriteHeader(response.StatusCode)

    if response.Status != "200 OK" {
        fmt.Println(response.Status)
    }

    result, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    output := string(result)
    fmt.Println(output)

    io.WriteString(res, output)
}
```

In general I need to forward that status from other URL that uses it and I need to keep it compatible.

Thank you very much in advance.

Jozef

Comment: What is your exact problem? What doesn't work for you in your current implementation? Do you want to write a proxy for some legacy API?

Comment: Yes, kind of... The problem is headers that need to be like <status code> <some status message>  Status message should contain an error description, but not that standard one like 400 Bad request, but 400 Required parameter is missing, or 400 No timestamp in request or so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `http.Hijacker` interface https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Hijacker to "hijack" (take over) the server's TCP connection to the client and write to it the custom response. Here is a modification of the example https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_Hijacker to return "400 Required parameter is missing" instead of the standard "400 Bad request" response to the client:

```
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        hj, ok := w.(http.Hijacker)
        if !ok {
            http.Error(w, "webserver doesn't support hijacking", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        conn, bufrw, err := hj.Hijack()
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        // Don't forget to close the connection:
        defer conn.Close()
        // non-standard HTTP status text and an HTTP header are written;
        // end of the Headers part of the messages is marked by extra \r\n
        bufrw.WriteString("HTTP/1.1 400 Required parameter is missing\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n")
        // write the body of the HTTP response message
        bufrw.WriteString("400 Required parameter is missing\n")
        bufrw.Flush()
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil)
}
```

Running this program and sending a curl request produces the desired response:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:9000/
HTTP/1.1 400 Required parameter is missing
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

400 Required parameter is missing
```

It should be straightforward to extend it to propagate other responses from your legacy API server.

**Edit** 
used `\r\n\r\n` in the example program to terminate the Headers portion of the HTTP response in accordance with the HTTP message standard (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3); separated `WriteString` calls for the headers and body of the HTTP response for clarity.

Comment: TIL! Thanks for that.

Comment: Wow that's pretty it, but how to write headers and content to that hijacked connection? Anyway, this is what I'm looking for. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I modified the program above to have separate bufrw.WriteString calls for headers and the body, separated with an extra `\r\n` empty line.  Of course, you can add more headers or copy them from the proxied connection.  Just remember, with hijacking you have the full control of what is written and are imitating the HTTP server - so for example if it is important to send the Content-Length header, you should calculate the response length and send the header "manually", as done with Content-Type in the example.

Comment: If you want a semi-proxy functionality you can do `response.Write(bufrw)` after hijacking.

Comment: This solution is perfect. I just added some \n s and \r s to make it work. Thank you very much :)